# Editar un archivo de excel por medio de C#

Tags: c#, excel

Quiero editar un archivo de excel, que similar a una factura, rellenar los campos de las columnas con los datos en los textbox que yo coloque, al momento de darle clic a un botón (Generar Fact.), se me abra el archivo con los datos ya agregados en los campos.

```
            //Inicie Excel y obtenga el objeto de la Aplicación.
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = true;
            //Get a new workbook.
            oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
            oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
```

En la parte donde dice (*//Get a new Woorkbok*)  quiero sustituir es para que me abra un archivo de Excel ya existente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar librerias basadas en `open xml` para acceder al excel y completar los datos en las celdas que necesites

Recomendaria analices las librerias

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

[SpreadSheetLigth](http://spreadsheetlight.com/)

la ventaja de estas librerias es que no necesitas de office instalado en la pc para poder generar el excel (si para visualizarlo)

No recomiendo que uses las librerias de Interop ya que estan basadas en COM y son para problenma

Comment: Que tal,  maestro Leandro, solo una pregunta ¿Tendrá información en su blog con muestra de código y con pasos sobre este tema?

Comment: no, no tengo ejemplos del uso de estas librerias, igual no son complejas de usa, en la seccion de documentacion se explican bastante completo

Answer (score 0):

sin usar la librería de interop de Microsoft también puedes utilizar que yo conozca NPOI, que quizás sea más fácil que usar la del open xml.

Aquí adjunto el link de nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/